# How do I translate JavaScript constructors to Amber Smalltalk?

Tags: javascript, constructor, amber-smalltalk

I use the [paperjs](http://paperjs.org/) graphical objects library with [Amber Smalltalk](http://amber-lang.net/).

I want to translate the following Javascript constructors for a [Point](http://paperjs.org/reference/point/) object to Amber Smalltalk

```
paper.Point(x, y)
paper.Point(array)
paper.Point(object)
paper.Point(size)
paper.Point(point)
```

The following Smalltalk

```
paper Point new inspect
```

gives a point

```
{ x: 0, y: 0 }
```

To construct an array in an Amber workspace I do

```
#(100 100)
```

The printIt is

```
 an Array (100 100)
```

However

```
 paper Point value: #(100 100)
```

gives nil as the result.

**Question**

How do I translate the `paper.Point(array)` constructor from JavaScript to Amber as well as the other constructurs?

**References**

1. http://paperjs.org/reference/point/
2. https://github.com/amber-smalltalk/amber/wiki/Wrapping-javascript-constructors-recipe
3. [Demo](https://github.com/hhzl/Amber-Paper-Demo) of translated code so far  (contains fabricjs and svg.js examples as well)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Amber Smalltalk equivalent of `new paper.Paper(100,100)` (JavaScript) is

```
paper Point newValue: 100 value: 100
```

This gives

```
 { x: 100, y: 100 }
```

**Reference**

https://github.com/amber-smalltalk/amber/wiki/Call-javascript-constructors-with-arguments